# Find active subdomains from list

Tags: dns, subdomain

I have a long list of subdomains that either are active or have been active. How could I quickly check all of these subdomains to see which are still active and which are no longer active?

Comment: That would seem to depend rather a lot on your definition of "active". "The name exists in DNS" and "A webserver at the address responds to requests" would be two reasonable definitions, for example.

Comment: Very true, I should have phrased it better. I am interested if they respond on port 80. But exist in DNS would also be good to know in my case.